# Is Crossover only connected to Genetic algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-algorithms

Is the idea of crossover only restricted to Genetic Algorithms ? 
Are there any other evolutionary algorithms that uses crossover(even under another name ) ? 
If an algorithm  uses crossover but does not utilize selection or mutation , should we call it a genetic algorithm ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crossover is a way of recombining solutions and is not limited to genetic algorithms. [Scatter search](https://www.uv.es/rmarti/paper/docs/ss8.pdf) is an example of a widely used meta-heuristic that recombines solutions systematically. A specific form of solution recombination is [path relinking](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4939-6530-4_8) and [Evolutionary GRASP](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4939-6530-4_9) is an example of a meta-heuristic based on it. Similar to a genetic algorithm it maintains a pool of good solutions and repeatedly recombines them by path relinking to find better solutions.

It may also be interesting to have a look at [Evolution strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_strategy), a subclass of evolutionary algorithms using mutation only.